# Flex Skinning and Adobe Illustrator

Tags: apache-flex, adobe-illustrator

I'm developing a skin for Flex 3 using Adobe Illustrator and I've just ran into a problem. I've designed a larger scrollBar skin to be used in a touch screen application but Flex seems to apply the default sizes regardless of the size of the symbol in the generated .swf. I could achieve the correct effect with .png but I'd like to know if it's possible using the previous method.

Answer (score 0):

Found it... i was mistakenly editing a symbol instance and not the symbol itself. Working just fine now.